# How long do tropical cuttings last?

Tags: cuttings

I would like to bring some pothos and philodendron cuttings with me on an international trip to give to a friend of mine. However, I'm not sure if they would actually survive the trip. Would cuttings of these sort survive an approximately 20 hour voyage?

Answer (score 5):

Check the customs regulations of the country you are going to before you try.  What you are allowed to take across international boundaries varies from country to country.  It would be a waste to take the cuttings only to have them confiscated (and you potentially fined) if they were not permitted.

If permitted, and put into a sealed plastic bag with a moist paper towel, the cuttings would most likely easily last 20+ hours.

Comment: Live plants are usually a no no at the border.